# How to pop an element in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pop the random chosen out of the array?
`var number = ["a", "b", "c"];`
`var random = number[Math.floor(Math.random()*number.length)];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use splice

```js
var number = ["a", "b", "c"];
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*number.length);

console.log(number[random], ' is chosen');
var taken = number.splice(random, 1);

console.log('after removed, ', number);
console.log('number taken, ', taken);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont understand the (random, 1), what does number 1 stand for?

Comment: @StevenTran have a read. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 2):

Use splice and the random number as the index.

```
number.splice(random, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Splice to remove a certain number of items from an array. This method will altar the original array and return the values removed.

The first argument in the Splice method is the starting point. The second argument is the number of items to remove.

**Example:**

```js
//            0    1    2
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];
var splicedItem = array.splice(1,1);

// The array variable now equals ["a", "c"]
console.log("New Array Value: " + array);
// And the method returned the removed item "b"
console.log("Spliced Item: " + splicedItem);
```

You can also use a negative number in the first argument to begin counting backwards from the end of the Array.

**Example:**

```js
//            -6   -5   -4   -3   -2   -1
var array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
var splicedItem2 = array2.splice(-3, 2);

// The array2 variable now equals ["a", "b", "c", "f"]
console.log("New Array Value: " + array2);
// The values removed were "d" and "e"
console.log("Spliced Item: " + splicedItem2);
```

You can even insert new items into the Array by including additional arguments. You also don't need to return the spliced items to a new variable if you don't want to.

**Example:**

```js
var array3 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

array3.splice(2, 2, "Pink", "Mangoes");

// The array3 value is now ["a", "b", "Pink", "Mangoes", "e", "f"]
console.log("New Array Value: " + array3);
```